# Generate Multiple CSV files from SQL Stored Proc data

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a stored procedure that returns huge record set upon execution.My requirement is to generate multiple CSV files via SSIS on a desired record count until it reaches the end of procedure returned records data.For example stored procedure returned 1 million records.I want to generate 10 CSV files having 100.000 records per each file.The number of CSV files generated should be based on count we chose to have on each csv file.What is the best way to achieve this via SSIS?
I did not get how loops can be used to achieve this.

Comment: Is the 10,000 meant to be a dynamic number or is it something like ...Pull Records and every 10K write to a file and then start another one. Or is it like Total Records Size Divided by N = how many records per file?

Comment: 10,000 is meant to be a dynamic number.If we chose 10,000, we have to create 10 different files pulling 10k records each time from 1 million records.If we chose 20k , we have to generate 5 different files.So the number of files generated is total records%number of records chosen per file

Comment: Being dynamic is it a formula or a user definer parameter that changes each run? Also note 1M / 10 = 100,000 not 10,000

Comment: Its a user defined parameter.We will set it through  a variable.Yes you are right , its 100,000 records per csv. I mistakenly put the wrong number.But its just an example of my requirement I am looking for.

Comment: er... why? is it because you want to open it in Excel? Or is it because you want to email it somewhere? Whats the real problem?

Comment: Nick ,CSV need to be processed through a exe which has few file size restrictions.And below link I mentioned in answer has the needed information to generate multiple files as I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link acted as a guide post and helped me to design a solution.I have made few changes in the implementation but the design is very helpful and nicely worked.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3172.split-a-flat-text-file-into-multiple-flat-text-files-using-ssis.aspx

Thanks to the article author.